# Django adding event to Month of a Calender issue

Tags: python, django

I am working on a Calender project, for the already got the code online. if booking an event we give a start date and end date. if submit the form the event will get saved in the calendar only on the start time, the event is visible in the calendar template, My requirement is that Now I want to modify the calendar so that all the dates matching the start date and end date should show the event.

Example: i have given the start date as 20th Dec 2020 and the end date as 24th Dec..
so in the calendar, the same event should show on 20,21,22,23,24... days

I believe here I am inserting the data in the Html template, i need to pass end time here that i don't know

```
        events_per_day = events.filter(start_time__day=day)
        d = ''

        for event in events_per_day:
            d += f'<li> {event.get_html_url} </li>'
```

Tried alot but no success

Below is the code :

**Models**

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()
@property
def get_html_url(self):
    url = reverse('cal:event_edit', args=(self.id,))
    return f'<a href="{url}"> {self.title} </a>'}
```

**utils,py**

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from calendar import HTMLCalendar
from itertools import groupby

from django.utils.html import conditional_escape as esc
from datetime import date

from .models import Event

class Calendar(HTMLCalendar):
    def __init__(self, year=None, month=None):
        self.year = year
        self.month = month
        super(Calendar, self).__init__()

    # formats a day as a td
#   # filter events by day

    def formatday(self, day, events):

        events_per_day = events.filter(start_time__day=day)
        d = ''

        for event in events_per_day:
            d += f'<li> {event.get_html_url} </li>'

        if day != 0:
            return f"<td><span class='date'>{day}</span><ul> {d} </ul></td>"
        return '<td></td>'

    # formats a week as a tr
    def formatweek(self, theweek, events):
        week = ''
        for d, weekday in theweek:

            week += self.formatday(d, events)
        return f'<tr> {week} </tr>'

    # formats a month as a table
    # filter events by year and month
    def formatmonth(self, withyear=True):
        events = Event.objects.filter(start_time__year=self.year, start_time__month=self.month)

        cal = f'<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="calendar">\n'
        cal += f'{self.formatmonthname(self.year, self.month, withyear=withyear)}\n'
        cal += f'{self.formatweekheader()}\n'
        for week in self.monthdays2calendar(self.year, self.month):
            cal += f'{self.formatweek(week, events)}\n'
        return cal
```

**Views.py**

```
# cal/views.py
import calendar

from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect

# Create your views here.
# cal/views.py

from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views import generic
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

from .forms import EventForm
from .models import *
from .utils import Calendar
#Calendar

class CalendarView(generic.ListView):
    model = Event
    template_name = 'cal/calendar.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        # use today's date for the calendar
        d = get_date(self.request.GET.get('month', None))
        print('d',d)
        context['prev_month'] = prev_month(d)
        context['next_month'] = next_month(d)
        #print('html_cal', cal)
        # Instantiate our calendar class with today's year and date
        cal = Calendar(d.year, d.month)
        print('cal', cal)
        # Call the formatmonth method, which returns our calendar as a table
        html_cal = cal.formatmonth(withyear=True)
        print('html_cal',html_cal)

       # print('html_cal1', html_cal)
        context['calendar'] = mark_safe(html_cal)
        return context

def get_date(req_day):
    if req_day:
        year, month = (int(x) for x in req_day.split('-'))
        return date(year, month, day=1)
    return datetime.today()


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('hello')

def prev_month(d):
    first = d.replace(day=1)
    prev_month = first - timedelta(days=1)
    month = 'month=' + str(prev_month.year) + '-' + str(prev_month.month)
    print('month',month)
    return month

def next_month(d):
    days_in_month = calendar.monthrange(d.year, d.month)[1]
    last = d.replace(day=days_in_month)
    next_month = last + timedelta(days=1)
    month = 'month=' + str(next_month.year) + '-' + str(next_month.month)
    return month


def event(request, event_id=None):
    instance = Event()
    if event_id:
        instance = get_object_or_404(Event, pk=event_id)
    else:
        instance = Event()

    form = EventForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
    if request.POST and form.is_valid():
        print('form',form)
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cal:calendar'))
    return render(request, 'cal/event.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use greater than or equal to & less than or equal to in filtering

```
events_per_day = events.filter(start_time__day__gte=day, end_time__day__lte=day)
```

Comment: I tried this code.. replaced with my old code... it is displaying 1 event  which is greater than today date all and all remaning date events not displaying

Comment: can you add `print(events_per_day)` and `print(d)` after the for loop and see what it is printing?

Comment: thank you for the answer with print(d) , i figured it out, actual the problem is what ever we are filing the date , same we are retrieving the data. so i need to fill the data w.r.t form